# How do I hide ONE line of code in the Command Prompt, not the whole window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, cmd.exe, timeout

Hello and sorry that this is short.

I was trying to make an application, using only a batch file. The code I used was:

```
@timeout /t 3 /nobreak
```

I did not want it to show anything, but it showed the message:

```
Waiting for 2 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit.
```

How do I hide just that single line of code?

Comment: Have you checked out the ECHO commands? What research have you done on this?

Comment: I did @ECHO OFF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
@timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul:
```

This redirects the message to the null device, which effectively suppresses the message.